# Show contents of .php files rather than variable names from array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm trying to make a simple news feed on my site that will show the latest 3 posts from a directory.

I have a directory full of .php files, inside each is some html and a short story with a link to the full page.

On my home page I've got

```
<?php
$news = scandir('news_posts', SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
include($news[0]);
include($news[1]);
include($news[2]);
?>
```

Which isn't working. I've tried print_r, var_export, echo, the best I've managed to do is have it print the names of the variables (so 14.11.14.php, 15.11,14.php, etc.) rather than the html content within the .php files.

This is probably really simple, but being new to .php I'm a little lost and can't seem to find an appropriate answer via search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scandir` only returns file names not the path, which seems to be `news_posts/`.  Try `glob`:

```
$news = glob('news_posts/*.*');
```

Or to keep using `scandir`:

```
include('news_posts/' . $news[0]);
```

I would use `glob` since you can return only files and only files with a specific extension.

```
sort($news, SORT_DESC);

foreach($news as $file) {
    include($file);
}
```

To `glob` and sort by time in one go:

```
array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', $news = glob('news_posts/*.*')), 
                SORT_DESC, $news);
```

Comment: That's perfect besides one thing, it's showing the earlier posts first. Is there a way I can reverse how it's sorted?

Edit: unsurprisingly array_reverse worked.

Thanks for pointing out glob, I had no idea it existed. Very useful.

Comment: Depends.  You are currently sorting on the name which is what I showed.  I added a goody for sorting by the modified time. Use `SORT_ASC` or `SORT_DESC`.